# Проверка файла на пустоту С++

Tags: c++, файлы

Решаю задачу на определение симметричности массива, ну или является ли полиндромом,иначе говоря. Если симметрична, то вывожу 1, иначе 0. В файле сначала вводится кол-во элементов массива,а потом только последовательность чисел.

Проблема в том, что никак не получается корректно проверить файл на пустоту. Если файл полностью пустой - вывести 0.

Я использовал и `if(!(fin >> number)) fout << 0;` и `if(fin.tellg() == 0)` и другие.
Но ответ в таком случае выводит неккоректно. Даже если ввел симметричную последовательность чисел в файл, выводит 0.

Посоветуйте что-то еще.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

bool symmetry(int array[], int begin, int end){
    {
        return (begin >= end) || ((array[begin] == array[end]) && (symmetry(array, begin + 1, end - 1)));
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    ifstream fin("input.txt");
    ofstream fout("output.txt");
    int number, count = 0, size, a = 0;
        
    if(!(fin >> number)) {fout << 0; return 0;} //проверка на пустоту

    while(fin >> number){a++;}
    fin.clear();
    fin.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        
    fin >> number;
    size = number;
    int array[size];
    if (size == 0){fout << 0; return 0;}
    
    if(size <= (a-1)){
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {fin >> number; array[count++] = number;}
    }
    else{
    for(int i = 0; i < a-1; i++) {fin >> number; array[count++] = number;}
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){cout << array[i];}

    if(symmetry(array, 0, count-1) == true) fout<< 1;
    else fout<< 0;
    
    fin.close();
    fout.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Никак не пойму, где в коде увы пытаетесь проверить файл на пустоту? И что такое пустота? Если в нем, например, одни пробелы или пустые строки, но нет чисел — это пустота?

Comment: Щас подправлю, а пустой имеется ввиду когда ничего нет в файле. @Harry

Comment: Ну и что не так? Если файла нет или в нем нет числа - создается `output.txt` с 0 внутри. А вы что хотите?

Comment: Ну так он всегда выводит 0. А это мне не нужно. Я хочу чтобы все было корректно. А именно, если я ввел симметрическую последовательность 4 1 2 2 1 (4 - это длин последовательности чисел,т.е 1 2 2 1), то он должен выдать 1, если он не симметричный, выдаст 0. А если файл пустой - выдает 0. Но сейчас он работает не так - он всегда выводит 0. А почему, мне вот это интересно. Как сделать так,чтобы было корректно

Comment: Тогда не морочьте голову вопросом о "проверке файла на пустоту". О пустоте вам ответили. Как-то странно спрашивать "как мне проверить, не открутили ли колесо у машины", а потом возмущаться — вы мне показали, как проверить колесо, но машина-то все равно не едет! Потому что вы неверно написали остальную часть программы.

Comment: Я Вас понял. Не беспокойтесь так. Это просто дотошность, пытаюсь разобраться, чтоб полность понять проблему. Если Вам не трудно, можете по подробнее сказать в чем проблема в остальной части программы? @Harry

Comment: Да сами посмотрите, вы же как минимум одно число не дочитываете... Грубо говоря, в файле `1 2 3 2 1`, а в массиве `1 2 3 2`...

Comment: 1. Я надеюсь Вы ввели длину последовательности перед тем как ввести саму последовательность.   2. Я добавил цикл for в код, с помощь которого вывожу содержимое массива, ошибку описанную Вами не вижу, к сожалению - @Harry

Comment: Конечно, ввел. Вы в курсе, что такое отладочный вывод? Выведите считанный массив, размер и так далее... `for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) cout << array[i] << " ";` перед вызовом `symmetry` и посмотрите, что там.  Я именно с этим примером и делал - `5 1 2 3 2 1`. Разбираться здесь с вашим кодом, в вопросе о том, как "проверить файл на пустоту" — как-то нехорошо. Так что этими своими заметками и ограничусь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверка на пустоту через `if(!(fin >> number))` - это корректная проверка на пустоту. Но ошибка возникает совсем по другой причине: в цикле `for(int i = 0; i < a-1; i++) {fin >> number; array[count++] = number;}` должен фигурировать не `i < a-1`, а `i < a`. Т.к надо cчитать до a-1 элемента **включительно**. Таким образом 1 непрочитанный элемент избавлял массив от симметричности и в файл, в качестве else, выдавался 0.